# Ionic build error: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have been having issues all day with building my ionic app..

I'm getting an error that reads:

> 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
>
> ** **BUILD FAILED** **

I've heard this can happen when you have a plugin installed that is a duplicate, however, running `ionic cordova plugin ls` I can't see anything that would be wrong:

```
branch-cordova-sdk 3.4.0 "branch-cordova-sdk"
com.omarben.inappreview 0.0.5 "inappreview"
cordova-clipboard 1.3.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk 5.4.30 "AppsFlyer"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 6.3.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 3.2.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.9.0 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic 5.4.6 "cordova-plugin-ionic"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid 1.3.2 "UniqueDeviceID"
cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.1 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.7 "SocialSharing"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.1 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
cordova-unique-device-id 1.3.2 "UniqueDeviceID"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? I've never had this specific error message before.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove one of these:

cordova-unique-device-id 1.3.2 "UniqueDeviceID"

cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"

Most of the time, this error occurs because you have two libraries that perform the same functionality.